# Check if File Exists on different Server

Tags: javascript

I need to see if a file exist on another server. So if I called http://www.someotherserver.com/index.html if the page is there it returns true and if not it returns false. I gave this a try:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: 'http://localhost/HTMLPage1.htm',
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Unable to connect to secure checkout.");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But it returns an error every time. I was thinking maybe because of cross-domain scripting.  Does anyone know how to make this work or have a method that does work?

Thanks!

Comment: You can add `crossDomain:true` parameter for a cross domain request. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The solution provided to this question, solved my problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163229/check-status-of-a-jquery-ajax-request

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Just set `crossDomain` to `true` in your code, like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: 'http://localhost/HTMLPage1.htm',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function () {
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Unable to connect to secure checkout.");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: As long as you are requesting a different server (as specified in the question), this does not work at all.